# URL Rewrite rule Conflicts in global.asax file C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to write a url like

`www.mydomain.com/some-user-page`

to achieve this i am using following line of code in global.asax file which is rewriting the URL as required
`routecollection.MapPageRoute("userpage", "{url}", "~/listing.aspx");`

but when i open `www.mydomain.com/default.aspx` it goes to `listing.aspx` page
then displays the default.aspx page how i can avoid execution of `listing.aspx` page

When i change the rewrite rule to `routecollection.MapPageRoute("userpage", "someuser/{url}", "~/listing.aspx");`
it works perfectly.
I need to stick with `www.mydomain.com/some-user-page`
I tried various web.config url rewrite rule but the problem is same.
is there any work around?

Comment: try this routes.Add("default", new System.Web.Routing.Route("home", new CustomRouteHandler("~/default.aspx"))); ??

Comment: could not find CustomRouteHandler

Comment: you can define any routehandler default or custom its just an example, try this https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series#:~:text=URL%20routing%20was%20a%20capability,not%20map%20to%20physical%20files. and let me know if you are stuck somewhere